# Update Facebook profile with Spring Social

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I'm using Facebook login on my site with Spring Social. I'm also creating an user in my database with specific application preferences for each Facebook user. After a user logs in, I want to update his personal information, like name and email, in my db. What will be the best way to do it and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it by implementing `ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent>`, which is called after the user logs in.

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent authEvent) {
    Authentication auth = authEvent.getAuthentication();
    if (auth instanceof SocialAuthenticationToken && auth.getPrincipal() instanceof User) {
        // every time a user authenticates through a social network, then we update his info from there
        User user = (User)auth.getPrincipal();
        // ... update user using ((SocialAuthenticationToken)auth).getConnection()
        // ... and save it
    }
}
```

There's also possible to do it by overriding [`ConnectionRepository#updateConnection`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/connect/ConnectionRepository.html#updateConnection(org.springframework.social.connect.Connection)).